# How to correctly adjust geom_label() within each sector of a pie chart?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to put labels for each value within each sector in a pie chart with `ggplot2`

My data:

```
simulpie1 <- data.frame(
  segtos = c("Perfil 1", "Perfil 2", "Perfil 3", "Perfil 4"),
  percents = c(26, 34, 30, 10)
)
```

The colors for each sector:

```
c("steelblue", "magenta", "orange", "lightgreen")
```

So...

```
26 - steelblue
34 - magenta
30 - orange
10 - lightgreen
```

I keep the order with this function:

```
simulpie1$segtos <- factor(simulpie1$segtos, levels = simulpie1$segtos)
```

And I used this argument (inside of `geom_label()`) to try to center the values ​​to the center of each sector:

```
position = ggplot2::position_stack(vjust = .5)
```

But, this result:

[image]

My plot code:

```
ggplot2::ggplot(data = simulpie1, ggplot2::aes(x = "", y = percents, fill = segtos)) +
  
  ggplot2::geom_col(color = "black") +
  ggplot2::coord_polar(theta = "y") +
  ggplot2::scale_fill_manual(values = c("steelblue", "magenta", "orange", "lightgreen")) +
  
  ggplot2::geom_label(
    ggplot2::aes(label = scales::number(
      percents, suffix = "%", accuracy = .1
      )
    ),
    fill = "#f2f2f2",
    colour = "#020202",
    size = 6,
    fontface = "bold",
    position = ggplot2::position_stack(vjust = .5)
  ) +
  
  ggplot2::theme(
    legend.title = ggplot2::element_text(face = "bold"), 
    legend.box.spacing = ggplot2::unit(-.7, "cm"), # distance between plot-legend
    legend.spacing.y = ggplot2::unit(.2, 'cm'), # distance between legend.title and all labels
    legend.key.size = ggplot2::unit(.5, "cm"), # size of labels
    legend.title.align = 0.5, # align legend.title
    axis.title = ggplot2::element_blank(),
    axis.text = ggplot2::element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = ggplot2::element_blank(),
    panel.grid = ggplot2::element_blank(),
    panel.background = ggplot2::element_rect(fill = "#f2f2f2", colour = "#f2f2f2"),
    plot.background = ggplot2::element_rect(fill = "#f2f2f2", colour = "#f2f2f2"),
    legend.background = ggplot2::element_rect(fill = "#f2f2f2", colour = "#008cba")
  ) + 
  
  # distance between legend.title and all labels
  ggplot2::guides(fill = ggplot2::guide_legend(byrow = TRUE)) + 
  
  ggplot2::labs(fill = "Segmentos")
```

I would like the values ​​to be centered in their respective sectors (colors).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As quite often the issue is the grouping. For the `geom_col` the grouping and the order of "stack" aka the slices of your pie are defined by the `fill` aes. However, for the `geom_label` you are overriding the grouping by setting the `fill` as an argument. Hence, to achieve the same grouping and to align the labels with the "slices" you have to be more explicit by mapping `segtos` on the `group` aes in `geom_label`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = simulpie1, aes(x = "", y = percents, fill = segtos)) +
  geom_col(color = "black") +
  coord_polar(theta = "y") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("steelblue", "magenta", "orange", "lightgreen")) +
  geom_label(
    aes(label = scales::number(
      percents,
      suffix = "%", accuracy = .1
    ), group = segtos),
    fill = "#f2f2f2",
    colour = "#020202",
    size = 6,
    fontface = "bold",
    position = position_stack(vjust = .5)
  ) +
  theme(
    legend.title = element_text(face = "bold"),
    legend.box.spacing = unit(-.7, "cm"), # distance between plot-legend
    legend.spacing.y = unit(.2, "cm"), # distance between legend.title and all labels
    legend.key.size = unit(.5, "cm"), # size of labels
    legend.title.align = 0.5, # align legend.title
    axis.title = element_blank(),
    axis.text = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks = element_blank(),
    panel.grid = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#f2f2f2", colour = "#f2f2f2"),
    plot.background = element_rect(fill = "#f2f2f2", colour = "#f2f2f2"),
    legend.background = element_rect(fill = "#f2f2f2", colour = "#008cba")
  ) +
  # distance between legend.title and all labels
  guides(fill = guide_legend(byrow = TRUE)) +
  labs(fill = "Segmentos")
```

[image]